# Best whitelist capable http proxy for Windows?

Tags: windows, http, proxy, whitelist

I would like to setup a http proxy on my work machine (no admin rights, WinXP) to only allow access to a whitelist of URLs. What would be the easiest solution? I prefer open-source software if possible.

Comment: This seems to have more to do with network/system administration than programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the Content Advisor in IE? You can provide a list of approved sites, anything else is blocked. Or do you want pass-through functionality like a true proxy?

Answer (score 1):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) seems to be the de facto proxy. This link describes how to set it up on a windows box: http://www.ausgamers.com/features/read/2638752

Answer (score 0):

Content advisor will ask for authorization every time a javascript function is called. At least that's my experience right now, and that's how I landed here, after hours of googling.

You are right, however, if the sites in the whitelist don't use javascript intensively and I would suggest that that option be tried first because (and I'm an IT person), it's FAAAAAAAAR easier to set up Content Advisor than a proxy server. Google "noaccess.rat" and you'll come accross articles that tell you how to set up IE using a white-list approach.

Having said this, however, you must be fully aware that Content Advisor can be easily disabled, even without knowing the password. One of my users did it in no time. You can find this in google as well.

Alex